# Apply CSS to classes that have name with numbers

Tags: html, css

This is the HTML:

```
<div class="class1">Class</div>
<div class="class2">Class</div>
<div class="class3">Class</div>
```

CSS is the following:

```
.class1, .class2, .class3 { ... }
```

I'm not sure if it's possible, but I'm trying to simplify the css.

Something like:

```
.class(from1to3) { ... }
```

Comment: could you not add a generic `class` class and a `id` to the divs?

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs I get the classes from a script that automatically makes the name with numbers

Comment: @PaulBorsan ah I see ... :/

Comment: In contrary to what you suggest this certainly would _not_ be a simplification. Sure, that line might get a bit shorter. But as a tradeof you would make understanding the styling rules _much_ more difficult. Also simple text searches for the class name would _not_ produce hits any more. Taking all together: that is _not_ a good idea. Keep things transparent. Only exception: if those classes are created in a dynamic manner, but that would be questionable anyway...

Comment: @arkascha Oh, okay! I will think of it. Thanks

Comment: hate when people mark question as favorite and not upvoting

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the class name will be the same for all elements, but with different numbers, you can use [Attribute Selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)

```css
div[class^="class"],
div[class*="class"] {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="class1">Class</div>
<div class="class2">Class</div>
<div class="class3">Class</div>
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use an attribute selector.

`div[class*='class'] {...}`

but the best solution i think is:

`.class1, .class2, .class3 { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

use `div[class*="class"]`

```css
div[class*="class"] {
    background: #ffff00;
}
```

```html
<div class="class1">Class</div>
<div class="class2">Class</div>
<div class="class3">Class</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using SASS or another pre-processor, it would be easier.